# geospatial query on mongo

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have the collection structure like:

```
{
name: "abcd",
location: {
type: "MultiPoint",
coordinates: [
[-73.57131,45.49758],[-73.57055,45.4984],[-73.57022,-73.57022],[-73.56968,45.49932],[-73.56896,45.50007],[-73.56807,45.50103],[-73.56722,45.50171]
]
}
}
```

I created index using

```
db.testCollection.createIndex( { coordinates: "2dsphere" })
```

Now I want to find nearby points from (lets say) [-73.56967,45.49933] out of the list location.coordinates thats present in my document.

So I queried

```
db.testCollection.find({ location:{ $near:{ $geometery:{ type:"Point", coordinates:[-73.56967,45.49933] }, $minDistance:0,$maxDistance:250}}})
```

but i got error:

```
Error: error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $geometry is required for geo near query",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

CAN SOMEONE HELP ME OUT PLEASE!

Comment: Did you write `db.testCollection.find({ location:{ $near:{ $geomet**e**ry:{...`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a spelling mistake. 
Use `$geometry` instead of $geomet**e**ry.

Try the following query

```
db.testCollection.find(
    { location:{ $near:{ $geometry:{ type:"Point", coordinates:[-73.56967,45.49933] }, 
                 $minDistance:0,$maxDistance:250}}
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

1. index name is incorrect

   db.testCollection.createIndex( { location: "2dsphere" })
2. as @mrp answer there is an spell mistake.  Use $geometry instead of $geometery.